# How to keep a track of packets at each interface in ONOS?

Tags: networking, ip, packet, sdn, onos

I have a one switch with four hosts connected to it. I want to keep a track of packets at each interface.

How can this be done using ONOS?

Comment: What do you mean by **I want to keep a track of packets at each interface.**, do you mean statistics, or packets copy or what?

Comment: Statistics at each interface

Comment: what is the make/model of the switch

Comment: Basically, through the traffic generator, I am sending Packets from 3 hosts to one particular host I want at each Interface how many have been sent and at the receiving end how many have been received.

Comment: This is an openVswitch

Comment: OVS support MIBs, Why not to use SNMP traps to pull stats from those ports into an SNMP server?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of stats on OVS ports can be done through `SNMP` traps and off-host `SNMP` server. You don't need ONOS for that.

[This wiki](https://wiki.opnfv.org/display/fastpath/Open+vSwitch+Virtual+switching+MIB+Support+and+reporting+of+flow+telemetry+via+IPFIX+-+High+Level+design) can be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Just type command "portstats" in ONOS CLI. And you can as well see in ONOS the GUI.